# Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 12 Could not find stored procedure 'SP_dboption'. IN SQL 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Declare @db varchar(255)
declare c cursor for
select name from sys.databases where is_read_only=0 and state=0 and name  NOT In ('master','model','tempdb','msdb')
open c
fetch c into @db
while @@fetch_status=0
Begin
      exec SP_dboption @db,'trunc. log on chkpt.','true' 
      DBCC shrinkdatabase (@db)
      fetch next from c into @db
End
close c
Deallocate c
```

Comment: So, where is your procedure `SP_dboption` located and where are you executing this script?

Comment: Deprecated. See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27879/sp-dboption-is-not-available-in-sql-server-2012

Answer (score 1):

`sp_dboption` was discontinued in SQL Server 2012.  See [Discontinued Database Engine Functionality in SQL Server 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144262(v=sql.110).aspx).

Furthermore, `'trunc. log on chkpt` was replaced with the `SIMPLE` recovery model in SQL Server 2000.  Time to update the code for modern versions.  `SHRINKDATABASE` should be avoided as it will introduce fragmentation.

Answer (score 0):

example: DB name is example , table name table1, procedure name is pro1 so you have to write as following :
exec example.dbo.pro1 (@parameter if you have)
select * from examole.dbo.table1